# Specify name of reference

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

See the MWE below. I want to achieve that, the `\nameref{c}` is printed as `Appendix` not as `Some Stuff`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

We refer to the \nameref{c}.

\lipsum

\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\chapter{Some stuff}\label{c}
\lipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Note that for some reasons I want to use `\renewcommand\thechapter{}` rather than `\chapter*{...}` plus `\addcontentsline...`.

This seems like a bit of a special situation. However, the following MWE shows an application which might be quite frequent:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

This is explained in the next chapter. 
%I want to set a link on "next chapter" which points to the second chapter

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

NB: I have rewritten my original question. It is now much more to the point and may also be more interesting for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\nameref` solves your problem, the example below also works without redefining `\thechapter` and adds an entry to the table of contents and the bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

We refer to the \nameref{chap:second}.

\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Second Chapter}
\chapter*{Second Chapter}
\label{chap:second}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

PS: This also works with `\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{}`, because in the solution the title of the chapter is referenced. I assume that you also want the string "Chapter"
without number at the start of the chapter above the chapter title and that
the numbering continues nevertheless.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

We refer to the \nameref{chap:second}.

\lipsum

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\label{chap:second}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

PPS: Third variant because of changed question.

The name title for `\nameref` is internally stored in `\@currentlabelname`. That can be redefined to a new string that will be read by the next `\label`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\SetNameTitle}[1]{%
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

We refer to the \nameref{c}.

\lipsum

\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\chapter{Some stuff}
\SetNameTitle{\appendixname}
\label{c}
\lipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

And a variant, where the reference text is replaced instead.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

We refer to the \hyperref[c]{\appendixname}.

\lipsum

\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\chapter{Some stuff}\label{c}
\lipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that I have reformulated by original question. Consequently, Heiko's answer, which perfectly solved the original problem, no longer does so. Therefore, I have unaccepted it.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! The last variant is exayctly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

We refer to the \hyperlink{c}{Appendix}.

\lipsum

\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand\thechapter{}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection\hypertarget{c}{}
\chapter{Some stuff}\label{c}
\lipsum

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

... and for the second MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

This is explained in the \hyperlink{c}{next chapter}. 
%Now the link points to the second chapter and is printed as "next chapter"

\lipsum[2]

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection\hypertarget{c}{}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```